# Flash ActionScript 3 reference an added child

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, addchild

I'm still new to actionscript, and I have a movieclip that is being added within a movieclip that is itself in a movieclip. I can add it there no problem. I am also trying to give it a name. Once I have added this movieclip, though, I cannot seem to reference it. Here is a piece of what my code looks like:

```
        var sky_m_1:sky_m_a = new sky_m_a();

        if (game_level.platforms.x==0 && !sky_m_1_tracker)
        {
            sky_m_1_tracker=true;
            sky_m_1.x=0;
            sky_m_1.y=game_level.platforms.y-183;
            sky_m_1.name="sky_m_x";
            game_level.sky_2_tracker.addChild(sky_m_1);
        }

        game_level.sky_2_tracker.sky_m_x.x=(game_level.platforms.x)/16;

        game_level.sky_2_tracker.sky_m_x.y=((game_level.platforms.y)/16)+442.3;
```

So I add this MC within an MC within an MC and then I want it to move. It doesn't, though. My code also seems to lock up after this point, and nothing below this segment works anymore. I get no errors though. Any help in how to correctly reference my MC would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is game_level and sky_2_tracker? Can you show us some more code?

Comment: game_level is just a movieclip with an instance name of "game_level." Same for sky_tracker_2, only that one is in game_level. I could show some more code, but those two movieclips aren't named in the code, their named on the stage in my Flash file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reference the new clip via the hierarchy in which it is nested. You can access the `x` and `y` properties of the new `object` via the instance name you've given it:

```
var sky_m_1:sky_m_a = new sky_m_a();

if (game_level.platforms.x==0 && !sky_m_1_tracker)
{
    sky_m_1_tracker=true;
    sky_m_1.x=0;
    sky_m_1.y=game_level.platforms.y-183;
    game_level.sky_2_tracker.addChild(sky_m_1);
}

sky_m_1.x=(game_level.platforms.x)/16;

sky_m_1.y=((game_level.platforms.y)/16)+442.3;
```

Comment: I tried that, but sky_m_1 doesn't move like it should when I enter the code that way. I've also tried:  <br/>

game_level.sky_m_1.x=(game_level.platforms.x)/16;  <br/>

game_level.sky_2_tracker.sky_m_1.x=(game_level.platforms.x)/16;  <br/>

But to no avail. That's what lead me to try and name the instance. I'm fine referencing it an almost any way, but nothing I have tried has worked.

Comment: What do you get if you trace the values sky_m_1 and game_level.platforms after the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have some problems in your logic/code:
You add the mc (short for movieclip) inside your "holder" (game_level) at this line:
*game_level.sky_2_tracker.addChild(sky_m_1);*
This line is inside a *If* statement - what happens if the *If* statement is false (the code inside it, doesn't run)? Your mc (sky_m_1) is not added to the display object list - so you can't access it.
*sky_m_1* (x/y) statements should be added inside the *If* statement.

Also you should try to rename the your variables so any developer could understand what you want to achieve.